# Eclipse Jee Neon Interaction as a Client with Agile PLM Version: 9.3.0.2 (Build 20)

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle-agile-plm

If I would like to use the API feature in Agile to interact with Eclipse Jee Neon. How might I do so. What are the steps in Eclipse that I must take in order to create this link. What am I doing wrong? Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 0):

You must add a reference to the AgileAPI.jar file for the version of Agile PLM you are connecting to. Then you create a connection to the Agile instance using boilerplate, such as referenced in the Getting Started guide:

```
private IAgileSession login(String username, String password) throws APIException 
{
    //Create the params variable to hold login parameters
    HashMap params = new HashMap();

    //Put username and password values into params          
    params.put(AgileSessionFactory.USERNAME, username);
    params.put(AgileSessionFactory.PASSWORD, password);

    // Get an Agile server instance. ("agileserver" is the name of the Agile     
    // proxy server, and "virtualPath" is the name of the virtual path used 
    // for the Agile system.)

    AgileSessionFactory instance =
        AgileSessionFactory.getInstance("http://<agileserver>/<virtualPath>");

    //Create the Agile PLM session and log in
    return instance.createSession(params);
}
```